# OCS 2007 R2 - other telephone number trouble

Tags: ms-office-communicator

I have the installation of Office Communications Server 2007 R2. There is a directory service (ADDS) user account named User1.

There is a list of "other" phone numbers in the properties of the User1  account:

[image]

The Address Book Service is configured and working properly.

When I want to make а call to User1 using Office Communicator 2007 R2, I can see only one "other" telephone number of User1:

[image]

I want to be able to see all the "other" telephone numbers in the list of User1's telephone numbers in Office Communicator 2007 R2.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I found the answer: OCS can process only one "other" number by design :-(

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: OCS can process only one "other" number by design :-(

Comment: Glad you solved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.